# Jar не видит файлы находящиеся в одной директории с ним

Tags: java, файлы, jar

Есть простенькая программа в которой я считываю информацию из файла, с помощью `FileInputStream`. Файл лежит в корневой директории проекта, на уровне с out и src, при запуске проекта в ***IntellijIDEA*** все работает прекрасно. Но как только я запускаю созданный `jar`, программа работает нормально, но почему то этот файл, программа начинает искать в папке пользователя Windows. Как сделать так, что-бы файлы брались из папки с `jar`? 
Для доступа к файлу использую следующую конструкцию:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Из jar'ника с помощью `FileInputStream` разве можно вообще файл прочитать? Смотрите в сторону метода `getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если файл `input.txt` находится внутри JAR, надо читать его через `getResourceAsStream()`
2. Если файл находится за пределами JAR, то `FileInputStream()` будет искать его в [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), который может зависеть от ОС, вариации:

   - текущий каталог - откуда запущен JAR
   - home directory

Для того, чтобы читать из каталога где лежит сам JAR, надо сделать одно из 2-х:

- запускать JAR из каталога где он лежит (в коде надо указать путь `'./input.txt`)
- в коде указать каталог где читать через: `new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
  .toURI()).getPath();` - где `MyClass` - один из классов, который упакован внутри JAR